# How can I create package folders using the shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have something like this:

```
package="com.program.interesting.program.aplication"
```

I want a script that will create folders like this:

```
midir com
cd com/
mkdir program
cd program/
...
etc
```

But I want to do this automatically, no matter how many folder I'll have. I guess this is very simple, but I don't know how to parse a string on the shell and I don't want to read a book, just to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert `.` to `/` and that is all:

```
mkdir -p "$(echo $package | tr . /)"
```

The `-p` key means that `mkdir` needs to create all necessary parent directories automatically.

Use `""` around the command substitution `$()` if it is possible that `$package` can contain spaces inside.

The `tr` command changes the `.` symbols in the string to slashes.

**e.g.**

```
$ echo com.program.interesting.program.aplication |tr . /
com/program/interesting/program/aplication
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p com/program/interesting/program/aplication
```